# How to play Vimeo video using Vimeo networking library?

Tags: android, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player, vimeo-android

I am using Vimeo for video hosting. But I don't know how to play video in my Android app. I have got the Vimeo-networking library here `'https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java'` but unable to play video. I am confused which code exacly used for playing video. Please help me. I am new to Vimeo.

```
String uri = what url?;
VimeoClient.getInstance().fetchNetworkContent(uri, new ModelCallback<Video>(Video.class) {
     @Override
     public void success(Video video) {
          //what to do now?
     }

     @Override
     public void failure(VimeoError error) {
          // voice the error
     }
});
```